# How to use multiple NSPredicates for multiple search values

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I'm using a UITextField as a search field: The user can input multiple search values separated by comma. By typing I want to find every custom object in my NSArray that matches one of the search component.

My custom objects have no properties (that can be used for the search). Receiving a value I have to call `[myObject fieldForKey:@"username"].value;`. Because of this I have to use `[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock]` (or another way was not possible for me).

My method for the search (will be called whenever a character was changed in the TextField):

```
-(void)searchEntriesWithString:(NSString*)searchString {
    NSArray *dataSource = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_allObjects];

    searchString = [searchString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSArray *components = [searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *value in components) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

        return ( [[(MyObject*)evaluatedObject fieldForKey:@"username"].wert hasPrefix:value ]);
        }];

        [predicates addObject:predicate];
    }

        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];

    NSMutableArray searchResultArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
}
```

Assuming following dataSource:

- Object1 with username "userA"
- Object2 with username "userB"
- Object3 with username "userC"

Calling the method with '[self searchEntriesWithString:@"userA,userB"]' should result in an array with Object1 and Object2.

But I don't get this result.

Comment: Maybe it isn't possible this way with NSPredicate? I removed the NSPredicate usage and use normal for loops. My App works now, but I'm still wondering why my code with NSPredicate isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you wanted **one** of the search components, not **all** of the search components, I think you should have used:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
```

As you had it using `andPredicateWithSubpredicates` a term would have needed to pass for "userA" *and* "userB".

[I realize you asked this three months ago, have found a work around, and moved on but thought I would just leave a suggestion]

Comment: I tested your suggestion and it's working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome... I've experienced the frustration of trying to get an `NSPredicate` to do what **I** want it to do.